# dismissViewController with button in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

So I am wondering what func to use for closing a detailed ViewController opened from a tableView. Currently I have it working to close the view, but the touches event occurs when you touch anywhere on the screen, not with a specific button. I have tried just using the button on storyboards but no luck. Below is what I have working so far (again not button specific)...

```
//DetailedViewController.swift
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Any and all feedback or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Put the button in the storyboard view controller and right-click-drag from the little circle for this action to the button. Alternatively, create your button programmatically and call `addTarget(self, action:"buttonAction:")` on the button.